# Pressed button effect for Native Android Facebook login

Tags: javascript, android, css, facebook-login, phonegap-build

My app uses phonegap build. I use facebook connect in order to log in to the app. I created two css styles for the button: normal one, and one with pressed look to be displayed after the button is pressed.

In browser and IOS it all works well, but in Android, the screen freezes after the user clicks the login button until the Facebook Login function starts (and the button icon is not changed).
I have no idea how to solve this (when removing the Facebook Login function, the css effect works).

Here is the code:

```html
loginP: function()
  {
            //Switch the css style to the pressed icon with the relevant pnd icon as the background
   var buttonFB=document.getElementById("login_button");       
   buttonFB.style.background = 'url("../app/images/login/FacebookButtonTightPressed.png")';
   buttonFB.style.backgroundRepeat  = "no-repeat";
   buttonFB.style.backgroundSize = "contain"; 
            //Start Facebook login
   Facebook.ConnectFromButton(function(data)
   {
    LoginPage.afterLogin(data);
   });
  }
```

Comment: are you listening for the 'deviceready' event? Did you implement "white-lists"? And if so, did you use the new white-list plugin? Did you bother to read any of the Docs?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JesseMonroy650 . I am listening to 'deviceready' event, and this button appears only after deviseready, and after all scripts were loaded. in the white-list I declare <access origin="*" />.

Answer (score 0):

What about the plugin? If you did not set the *phongap-version*, you will default to leading edge and you will NEED the plugin, and you are also subject to random transient bugs. This line in your *config.xml*

`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />`